# In any language, is there a word for a death relationship with one’s sibling?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, kinship-terms

In English, we have the word “widowed” for losing a spouse and “orphaned” for losing a parent. Is there any equivalent for one’s sibling in any language?

Comment: *Widowed* and *orphaned* are both relevant for legal purposes. I don't know of any examples, but for *bereaved of sibling* I would look at cultures where the firstborn has different rights.

Comment: @Keelan That’s still quite broad – firstborn children (boys, in most cultures) have enjoyed special privileges throughout history all over the world, particularly inasmuch as inherited titles (kings, emperors, etc.) are concerned.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree, though I would look at cultures where this is the case throughout society, not just in royal circles. It's still a big pool of course. // The closest I can think of is Biblical Hebrew גֹּאֵל *goʾēl*, the term for a 'redeemer': a man who is obliged to marry his deceased brother's wife to produce offspring in his place. But it is only used in this specific legal context, you wouldn't go around saying "I am a redeemer" meaning "I have lost a brother". There are simply much fewer contexts in which you need to communicate this than for *widow* and *orphan*.

Comment: Pitjantjatjara (Pama-Nyungan, Australia) has a word for someone who has lost a sibling (in addition to words that equate to 'orphan', 'widow' or 'widower).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Could you share this word? Thanks

Comment: @JonahWeaver sorry, just noticed your question: _tjitjurruru_ [ˈcicʊɾʊɹʊ] 'man/boy whose sibling has died'.  _tjiturla_ [ˈcitʊɭɐ] 'person whose mother, father, aunt or uncle has died'. _purkutjara_ [ˈpʊɾkʊcɐɾɐ] 'person whose child, nephew or niece has died'.